# Get two query results with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Can I get two results from PHP server side ?
I want data and seta to be populated both after the AJAX success.

Here is my HTML and javascript code:

```
<body>
    <div align="center" id="box"></div>
    <hr>
    <div align="center" id="tox"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var SeeID = 89;
        var SeeID2 = 88;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "server.php",
            data: "SeeID="+SeeID+"&SeeID2"+SeeID2,
            success: function(data,seta){
              $('#box').html(data);
              $('#tox').html(seta);
                }

            });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is my PHP server side code:

```
if (isset($_POST['SeeID'])) {
    $SeeID = $_POST['SeeID'];
    $QLoadFeild = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE id='".$SeeID."'");
    $X = $QLoadFeild->fetch(); 
    $name = $X['name'];
    $family = $X['family'];
    echo '<div>'.$name.'</div><div>'.$family.'</div>';
}

if (isset($_POST['SeeID2'])) {
    $SeeID2 = $_POST['SeeID2'];
    $QLoadFeild = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE id='".$SeeID2."'");
    $X = $QLoadFeild->fetch(); 
    $name = $X['name'];
    $family = $X['family'];
    echo '<div>'.$name.'</div><div>'.$family.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: please be more specified. Its not clear here.

Comment: from your code it seems that you've made an ajax post request on page load once. but you've displayed the same response on two different div, this is what I think is creating a confusion, you're seeing response twice.

Comment: you can only return one response from ajax request, but you may work around this by return your php response in an array then decode it into json and then handle it with ajax .

Comment: @HassanAhmed Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP Try to push it into array and return as JSON value,

```
$outputArr = array();
if (isset($_POST['SeeID'])) {
    $SeeID = $_POST['SeeID'];
    $QLoadFeild = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE id='".$SeeID."'");
    $X = $QLoadFeild->fetch(); 
    $name = $X['name'];
    $family = $X['family'];
    $outputArr[] = '<div>'.$name.'</div><div>'.$family.'</div>';
}

if (isset($_POST['SeeID2'])) {
    $SeeID2 = $_POST['SeeID2'];
    $QLoadFeild = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE id='".$SeeID2."'");
    $X = $QLoadFeild->fetch(); 
    $name = $X['name'];
    $family = $X['family'];
    $outputArr[] = '<div>'.$name.'</div><div>'.$family.'</div>';
} 
echo json_encode($outputArr);
```

And in JS Success function

```
 success: function(data,seta){
            var datas = JSON.stringify(data); // use it further
          }
```